# Finding minimum distance in a binary search tree

Tags: binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree in which I am trying to find the minimum distance using the following characteristic:

`distance = [a + b - x]`

where a and b are nodes and x is a value given by the user. I'm not sure how to do this. I thought I would start at the root of the tree and then use in order traversal to index all the nodes and then maintain a separate array that I can then compare all the absolute values but this seems inefficient.......

Comment: Can you include an example in an actual diagram, which labels `a`, `b`, along the value `x` ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/7Tibw   Perhaps a tree like that and X is 5.

Comment: @IskKander, I'm having trouble getting your question, your image is not a bst